# Where is the $\int_0^t\Delta F$?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

$Rm$ is curvature tensor , and the $g_{ij}$ meet Ricci flow.

For getting the inequality 1 in the below [paper's 191th page](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947) , I compute that:
$$
\because ~~~\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\leq \Delta F+\overline{C}M^3\\
\therefore ~~~
\int_0^t\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\leq 
\int_0^t\Delta F+\int_0^t\overline{C}M^3\\
\therefore ~~~
F(t)-F(0)\leq \overline{C}M^3t+\int_0^t\Delta F  \\
\therefore  ~~~~
F(t)\leq F(0)+ \overline{C}M^3t+\int_0^t\Delta F
$$
But in the below picture ,there is not $\int_0^t\Delta F$, Why ?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the goal is to get an estimate $|\nabla Rm|^2 \le C/t$ which is in particular independent of spatial position, I think that what's going on here is a maximum principle argument. As written the inequality you have highlighted does not hold pointwise - you're correct that it should be $$F(x,t) \le F(x,0) + \bar C M^3 t + \int_0^t \Delta F(x,s)ds.$$

However, if we replace $F(x,0)$ with the maximum value of $F$ at time zero it is true: $$ \tag{1} F(x,t) \le \sup_x F(x,0) + \bar C M^3 t. $$

Since the second inequality was estimating $F(0) = A|Rm|^2 \le AM^2$ anyway, this weaker version is still bounded above by $F \le (A+\bar C)M^2$.

You can deduce $(1)$ by noticing that $G(x,t) = F(x,t) - \bar C M^3 t$ satisfies $\partial_t G \le \Delta G$ and applying the weak parabolic maximum principle to $G$: since $G$ is bounded above by the constant $\sup_x F(x,0)$ at the initial time, this bound persists for all time.

Comment: So clever you are. Thanks very much.

Comment: @lanse2pty: I'm just familiar with the subject, you get a feel for what tricks people are using after a while. You seem to be having trouble learning from this paper - perhaps you would be better off with a more introductory text alongside it? My usual recommendation is freely available at http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~andrews/book.pdf. For example their proof of Shi's estimate (Chapter 7.1) includes both a precise definition of the $*$ notation as well as explicitly invoking the maximum principle. I think it's always good to have multiple references, anyway.

Comment: When I download your recommendation, I find that  my teacher also recommended   it to me  at not long ago. Thanks very much.

Comment: I feel the maximum principle is not right. Let $G(x,t)=t+x^2$,$x\in [0,1],t\in[0,1]$ then ,$\partial_tG\leq \Delta G$, and ,$G(x,0)=x^2\leq 1$,but when $x=1,t=1$, $G(x,t)=2>1$

Comment: I think I understand it in a wrong way.But I don't know where the wrong is.

Comment: @lanse2pty: the maximum principle requires something like Dirichlet boundary conditions to work - in your example the boundary conditions are increasing in time, so it doesn't work. In this problem we are working on a compact manifold so there is no issue. See Chapter 6.2 of Hopper-Andrews for the proof and some applications of the maximum principle on compact manifolds.